# How to set WebView properly in fixed size properly

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewbinding

I implement webview in recyclerview item and Webview result does not set properly.
[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUTcF.png)

Comment: To get help you have to show the relevant code depicting what you have done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to build the tab minimising functionality similar to chrome/firefox, instead of using webview inside the minimised items, you can map every page to an image and store it internal storage, also, you don't want the user to interact with pages in minimised state, so webview is not required.